# Emacs does not use swapped alt&win after xmodmap runs? (GUI emacs)

Tags: package, package-repositories

I have a mac-book-air. I swapped my Alt  & Win with xmodmap as per [linux post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86933/swap-alt-and-super#_=_) like so:

```
keycode 64 = Alt_L
keycode 133 = Super_L
remove Mod1 = Alt_L
remove Mod4 = Super_L
add Mod1 = Super_L
add Mod4 = Alt_L
```

Then I apply it via:

```
xmodmap xmodmap.file
```

Now my Alt+tab works properly, but in Emacs meta(alt) and Super(cmd) are not swapped. I.e, s-x and M-x are not swapped. After 3 hours of googling around I've not made more progress.

Do you have any tips/advise/things to try? (I'm very desperate). 
Is it possible to re-map these from inside emacs itself?

Background:
 - I'm using MATE Desktop.
 - I tried Gnome Tweak Tool to swap alt & cmd, but it doesn't seem to function under MATE Desktop.

**[Edit]**
- This issue occurs only in GUI version of emacs. In terminal it get's the right keys.
- I have tried re-starting emacs, restarting system, applying the change then start emacs. No Luck.

Comment: Something very similar works for me, although I'm using KDE. One thing that may help narrow the issue: are you using Emacs with graphical interface or the console version?

Comment: Did you restart Emacs? IIRC some things in the X11 library are initialized once and for all and this sometimes causes modifier remappings to behave oddly.

Comment: This happens only in GUI version. (good question btw, doesn't happen in terminal verison). I did do a hard-kill of emacs (pkill emacs) and restarted it, but no luck :-/.

Comment: Hello! Running the same issue.. Did you manage to solve it?